# Is a separator or grouping for key/values in settings psmultivaluespecifier possible?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is a separator or grouping for key/values in settings psmultivaluespecifier possible?

For example, via settings, out of app, user selecting values is presented with separated or grouped titles.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: I was looking for a way to be able to improve the look and arrangement of user settings "outside running app" i.e. via settings --> <the app>. But this has limitations of course as it it constructed from rules in the settings.bundle. I have resigned to the fact that more elaborate presentations of user settings can for now only be done "inside the running app" i.e. what we build and code for ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting self answer below to avoid anyone wasting effort on this one....

A developers ability to improve the look and arrangement of user settings "outside running app" i.e. via settings --> . has limitations, as it it constructed from rules in the settings.bundle. It is designed to create it for you automatically.

More elaborate presentations of user settings can (for now) only really be done "inside the running app" i.e. what we build and code for ourselves.

Comment: ah, that is right. I struggle also to modify settings to my taste through native settings.app, but it is not possible at the moment.